# Method definition: how can I use class property as a default function parameter?

Tags: php, oop

First I tried to declare the following class:

```
class MyClass{
  public $min;
  public $max;
  function my_func($min=$this->min,$max=$this->max){
  }
}
```

PHP throws `syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE` error. So I need to do something like this:

```
class MyClass{
  public $min;
  public $max;
  function my_func($min=NULL,$max=NULL){
    if(!isset($min)) $min = $this->min;
    if(!isset($max)) $max = $this->max;
  }
}
```

Which trows no errors (I didn't tested this code but I think it should work).

However this approach has several drawbacks:

1. I can not transfer `NULL` as a value to the function as default values will be used instead.
2. This is lengthy

Is there any better solution?

**EDIT 1**

As proposed by @nickb I can use constants:

```
class MyClass{
    const MIN = 0;
    const MAX = 10;

    function my_func($min = MyClass::MIN, $max = MyClass::MAX) {
    }
}
```

This is a good solution except a case the $min and $max intended to change from time to time:

```
$a = new MyClass();
$min = 0;
$max = 10;
$b = new MyClass();
$a->MyFunc(1,2);
$b->MyFunc();
```

Unfortunately this is my case :(

It is probably a forced scenario and I shouldn't built such 'flexibility' to the class but this is exactly what I planned to do. I should add a note: I'm really a novice at OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use constants:

```
class MyClass{
    const MIN = 0;
    const MAX = 10;

    function my_func($min = MyClass::MIN, $max = MyClass::MAX) {
    }
}
```

You just have to keep in mind that the default values must be constant expressions. From [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about it. However I added an EDIT 1. Could you take a look?

Comment: @VladaKatlinskaya - You can't use default values for this. You want it to be dynamic, yet default values must be static.

Comment: Didn't know about this :(
I found in the docs: `The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.`.
Could you explain is there any reason that PHP has this restriction? I think that sometimes it can be useful...

Comment: @VladaKatlinskaya - It's probably for the same reason you can't initialize a member variable with a dynamic expression too.